# Can I disable tooltip when the browser is at a certain screensize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I wrap the code at the bottom in bootstrap hidden classes or is it only with something like the snippet immediately below?

```
if ( $(window).width() < 960 ){
 //function
}

<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).on('ready', function () {
            $('body').tooltip({
                selector: '.with-tooltip',
                placement: 'left',
                html: 'true'
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it related with Javascript  & Jquery